# perspective causes overflow errors i Firefox

Tags: css, firefox, perspective

I'm trying to set up parallax using CSS perspective and `translateZ`, but getting some weird overflow errors in Firefox.

http://jsbin.com/fiviyefeme/1/edit?html,css,js,output

As you can see, when moving the mouse around, the background-image gets cropped. But I really can't see why they would do that. I've also tried using `preserve-3d`, but that only makes them dissapear.

Answer (score 0):

Can only see a white background in the link that you provided. I have also checked the css and it doesn't have any background image on it:

```
body {
  perspective: 800px;
}
```

Have you updated this?

Comment: The divs should have a background-image: `background-image: url('http://www.mustasj.no/dynamic/upload/bilder/blogg/pal/mustache.png');`